# docker-compose stuck on building

Tags: angular, docker

I have an app Django in back-end and angular in front-end. It builds and works with no issue locally.

Now I want to create docker image for front-end. I have already create it for django and it work well.

But when i added docker file for angular, and when i'm trying to build container of front-end it stuck in
Building frontend

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11.2-alpine as node

# Set working directory.
RUN mkdir /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend

# Copy app dependencies.
COPY package*.json ./frontendd

# Install app dependencies.
RUN npm install

# Copy app files.
COPY . /frontend
RUN npm run build
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ....some of code...
  frontend:
     container_name: frontend_dev_blog
     build: ./frontend
     command: "npm start"
     volumes:
       - ./frontend:/frontend
     ports:
       - "4200:4200"
     expose:
       - "4200"
```

Comment: We probably need to see the output of the command you're running.

Comment: it's stuck in "Building frontend"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if you have `.dockerignore` setup properly or not. In my case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of memory I guess for Angular build process.

Try adding `shm_size: '128m'` to `build` section of `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Still same problem